# Check if a DayOfWeek is within two specified DayOfWeek's

Tags: c#, extension-methods, dayofweek

I have a `DayOfWeek` and I need to check to see if this day is between two other `DayOfWeek` variables.

For example:

```
DayOfWeek monday = DayOfWeek.Monday;
DayOfWeek friday= DayOfWeek.Friday;

DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;

if (today is between monday and friday)
{
   ...
}
```

*Note: These days would be inclusive. In this case, if the day is **Monday**, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and **Friday**, then it's valid.*

The only thing I can think of is doing a massive if statement in a different method, perhaps an **extension method**, but this isn't very elegant.

**Edit**

Here is an example of my requirements:

```
    public enum RecurringModes
    {
        Minutes,
        Hours
    }

    public RecurringModes RecurringMode { get; set; }
    public int RecurringValue { get; set; }

    ... 

    public IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDueDatesToday()
    {
        //Get the current date (starting at 00:00)
        DateTime current = DateTime.Today;

        //Get today and tomorrow's day of week.
        DayOfWeek today = current.DayOfWeek;
        DayOfWeek tomorrow = current.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek;

        //If it isn't in the date range, then return nothing for today.
        if (!IsInDateRange(today, StartingOn, EndingOn))
            yield break;

        while (current.DayOfWeek != tomorrow)
        {
            //Check the selected recurring mode
            switch (RecurringMode)
            {
                //If it's minutes, then add the desired minutes
                case RecurringModes.Minutes:
                    current = current.AddMinutes(RecurringValue);
                    break;
                //If it's hours, then add the desired hours.
                case RecurringModes.Hours:
                    current = current.AddHours(RecurringValue);
                    break;
            }

            //Add the calculated date to the collection.
            yield return current;
        }
    }

    public bool IsInDateRange(DayOfWeek day, DayOfWeek start, DayOfWeek end)
    {
        //if they are all the same date
        if (start == end && start == day)
            return true;

        //This if statement is where the problem lies.
        if ((start <= end && (day >= start && day <= end)) ||
            (start > end && (day <= start && day >= end)))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Effectively, the method `AllDueDatesToday()` will return a list of `DateTime` which represents a schedule for today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare enums as if they were numbers:

```
if (today >= monday && today <= friday) {
```

As @Tyrsius points out, this only works because `monday < friday`. So, technically, you need to check that first:

```
if ((monday <= friday && (today >= monday && today <= friday)) ||
    (monday > friday  && (today <= monday && today >= friday))) {
```

**Note that .NETs week starts at Sunday: DayOfWeek.Sunday is 0.**

If you want your week to start at Monday, you have to perform some arithmetic.

```
var lowLimit = ((int)monday + 6) % 7;
var highLimit = ((int)friday + 6) % 7;
var valueToCheck = ((int)today + 6) % 7;

if ((lowLimit <= highLimit && (valueToCheck >= lowLimit && valueToCheck <= highLimit)) ||
    (lowLimit > highLimit  && (valueToCheck <= lowLimit && valueToCheck >= highLimit))) {
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work, since the numbers don't wrap. It will fail, for example, on "is monday between saturday and tuesday"

Comment: I'm not sure if your second if statement works correctly. I ran it through using today variable being `Wednesday`, the start date (monday variable) being `Monday`, and the end date (friday variable) being `Sunday`. No luck unfortunately. - I'll update the question to provide further information.

Comment: .NET's week starts at Sunday.

Comment: Ah! Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can use enums in logical comparisons but there is an issue where the values don't wrap around.  And the order of the end points matter. For example "Is Monday between Saturday and Tuesday" should return `true` whereas "Is Monday between Tuesday and Saturday" should return `false`.

```
public static bool IsBetween(this DayOfWeek weekday, DayOfWeek inclusiveStart, DayOfWeek inclusiveEnd)
{
    if (inclusiveStart <= inclusiveEnd)
    {
        return (weekday >= inclusiveStart) && (weekday <= inclusiveEnd);
    }
    return (weekday >= inclusiveStart) || (weekday <= inclusiveEnd);
}
```

This should work.  There are others ways to do it but this is one way.